# c# listbox selected change row event works but row is not selected

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a problem. I have three buttons of main categories and when you click one of these buttons some things appear in ListBox and the buttons with subcategories appear. If you click on subcategory, consequently different things appear in ListBox.

I have methods like that:

```
private void DisplayPeople(string category); //I use it ParentClicked and SubClicked
private void ParentClicked(object sender, EventArgs e); //for parent category
private void SubCatClicked(object sender, EventArgs e); //for subcategory
myListBox.SelectedIndexChanged+= new EventHandler(selectedIndexChange);
```

When you select sth in listbox then it should appear in my DataGridView and it works perfectly. However, when I click on the button and things appear in listbox, and I put sth like  **myListBox.ClearSelected();** or **my.SelectedItem = null;** I see NOTHING is selected at the begining but still SelectedIndexChange event works because it adds first row to my DataGridView. I have no idea why, could u help me?

MUCH MORE SHORTER:
In my program when you select **sth** in ListBox, it appears in DataGridView. When i set  **myListBox.ClearSelected();** or **my.SelectedItem = null;**, nothing is selected in the begining but **SelectedIndexChange** event works and first thing in listbox is added to **DataGridView**. I don't want that, I want it to appear in datagridview only when it is selected by the user.

NOW MY EVENT HANDLER LOOKS LIKE THAT:

```
private void selectedIndexChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Person person = (Person)MyListBox.SelectedItem;
  if (MyListBox.Items.Count > 0 && MyListBox.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            Basket.Add(person);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = Basket;
        }
    }
```

PS.
I SOLVED THE PROBLEM. I did it that the thing from listbox is added to DataGridView when user clicks on ListBox and SelectedIndexChange event appears. But maybe there is simpler and prettier solution?

Comment: Please show us the code in SelectedIndex Change event of listbox...

Comment: I updated my main post;)

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly how `SelectedIndexChanged` is supposed to work.

What you have to do is compare `myListBox.SelectedIndex` to -1 or `myListBox.SelectedItem` to `null` to see if something is actually selected in the ListBox.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
 private void myListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        if (myListBox.Items.Count > 0 && myListBox.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            //Do something in DatagridView
        }
        else
        {
            //clear the gridview
        }           
   }
```

Comment: It doesn't work also... But... I think where is the problem. When I click one button, then the event selectedindexchange appears two times! At first it has selecteditems.count = 1 (then sth id added to dataGridView) and then after a secomd selecteditems.count = 0....

Comment: I thought is because I clear selected index too many times, but when I do it only one time, the selectedindexchange still works two times...